# UINavigationController undoes changes to previous UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a navigation controller with a couple of view controllers in it. In the first view controller (the app's initial one) I perform an animation, which moves two UIImageViews around, and fades in some additional ui elements. Now, when I push the next view controller and then go back to the initial one, the transformations are gone and the image views are exactly where they were when loaded from the storyboard. The additional ui elements, however, are still visible and so is the text I've entered in some UITextFields. So the view controller is not entirely reset to its initial state but somehow the performed animations are undone. Can anybody tell me whether this is regular behavior and - if so - how I can preserve the transformations?

A little more disclosure: I'm simply setting off a regular animation upon hitting a button...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     self.firstView.center = firstCenter;
                     self.secondView.center = secondCenter;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     // Upon complection fade in additional ui elements
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                                      animations:^{

                                          self.firstElement.alpha = 1.0;
                                          self.secondElement.alpha = 1.0;
                                          self.thirdElement.alpha = 1.0;
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                          [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                      }];
                 }];
```

... and then pushing the next view controller after hitting another button.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_nextViewController animated:YES];
```

As far as I can see I'm not doing anything funky here, so any help is appreciated.